# Switch firefox to use a different DNS than what is in the windows.host file

Tags: firefox, dns

For example, I have a development site on a different server but I'm trying to copy content over from the live site so it'd be handy to have the live site in IE and the dev site in FF.

I tried FoxyProxy but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Why would you downvote this?  Using different DNS names is obviously the normal way to do this, but having firefax override DNS is still an interesting problem.

Comment: @jj33 it would also be an interesting problem if you forgot you'd done it. that might take some time to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the SwitchHost extension exactly for this problem:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14258

It is easy to configure, and even more easy to switch hosts.

Comment: It seems to switch /etc/host files and not dns servers.

Comment: Not available for Firefox 9.0.1

Answer (score 15):

I use this to override system's DNS with localserver

in about:config

change this value:

`network.dns.forceResolve`

`network.dns.ipv4OnlyDomains`

`network.dns.localDomains`

with IP address of local DNS server (for exsample 192.168.1.88)

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 13):

It's now possible, with the `DNS over HTTPS` function:

Open Options, General, scroll to very bottom and open Network Settings,

On the very bottom, you can find DNS over HTTPS:

[image: dnsOverHttps]

---

You had to use `about:config` before to change this setting, here's for documentation:

Type `about:config` in firefox address bar.

search for: 
`network.trr.uri`

You can use one of the DNS servers below:

```
Cloudflare: https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query
Google: https://dns.google/dns-query
Secure DNS EU: https://doh.securedns.eu/dns-query
Quad 9: https://dns.quad9.net/dns-query
```

And set `network.trr.mode` to 1

Hijacked from here:
https://www.ghacks.net/2018/04/02/configure-dns-over-https-in-firefox/

Comment: But that requires the DNS server to support DNS over HTTPS.

Comment: Basically the DNS server should support port 443 like OpenDNS which I did not mention in the post.

Comment: You can configure this in the main settings now. No need for `about:config`.

Comment: @Shayan  `network.trr.mode` value must be set to `3` if you want all DNS traffic to go through DoH and want to avoid native (i.e., OS DNS) completely.
Make sure that DoH is working otherwise you will not be able to access any site due to DNS lookup failure

Comment: Cloudflare can also be configured as `https://1.1.1.1/dns-query`

Answer (score 6):

It appears from your question that you already have a second set of DNS servers available that reference the development site instead of the live site.

I would suggest that you simply run a standard SOCKS proxy either on that DNS server system or on a low-end spare system and have that system configured to use the development DNS server.  You can then tell Firefox to use that proxy instead of downloading pages directly.

Doing it this way, the actual DNS lookups will be done on the proxy machine and not on the machine that's running the web browser.

Answer (score 5):

DNS resolving is usually done at the system level and not at the application level, so you can't normally have one program use one dns and another program use a different dns. I'm not aware of any firefox extensions that allow you to use a different dns.

Comment: Firefox (now) does DNS lookups internally, so it should be possible to configure a different DNS server somewhere.

Comment: @Shayan that only works for DoH providers. Of which, there are [apparently only 3 in existence currently](https://medium.com/@nykolas.z/dns-security-and-privacy-choosing-the-right-provider-61fc6d54b986#c481), 2 of which are run by giant, creepy companies; the third being not a pure DNS provider (rather, a parental filter). Definitely not a general-purpose solution, nor is it relevant to OP's situation which needs to connect to a specific, pre-existing (almost certainly non-DoH) server.

Answer (score 3):

What about having different names for your dev and prod servers? That should avoid any confusions and you'd not have to edit the hosts file every time.

Comment: Maybe he needs to move data from one server to another, and change DNS?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you could write a custom rule for Fiddler to do what you want?  IE uses no proxy, Firefox points to Fiddler, Fiddler uses custom rule to direct requests to the dev server...

http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/

Comment: Yes, this is possible (and simple - [see the Fiddler Cookbook](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp), it's approx. fifth example from the top) - in addition, newish Fiddler betas have this useful feature built-in (`main menu->Tools->HOSTS...`).

Answer (score -1):

Since http proxy protocol is similar to raw http protocol, you can redirect desired traffic to your development server by telling firefox it's a proxy server.

two limitations:

A. this won't let you use https connections.

B. some frameworks (e,g: wordpress) don't like this method and redirect the request the wrong way

just copy the following code into a .pac file (enter your site domain and IP address, of course), and switch development/production just by changing proxy configuration.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    var prox4site = {
        "mysite.com":"PROXY 10.0.1.100:80",
        "www.mysite.com":"PROXY 10.0.1.100:80"
    }

    return prox4site[host] || "DIRECT";
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Go to options->Advanced->Network->Settings->Automatic proxy configuration url and enter 8.8.8.8 All you Mozilla traffic uses Google dns now.

Comment: The proxy is not the DNS!