# Firefox addon,javascript, stop HTTP/DNS request

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, dns

I have this simple piece of code in my JS file:

```
AdultURL_FilterUrl = second_node.getElementsByTagName('filterdomain')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                    window.stop();
```

Which basically checks if the URL (is on and) equals the adultURL blocklist, and stops the window from loading.
But is there anyway to stop the http request so that it does not register on the adult site?

Even better if it is possible to stop it before the DNS request is sent.

Comment: See also this (older but still relevant) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495553/firefox-dns-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this article on CodeProject a while ago: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DnsHijack.aspx

What it does is hook the `gethostbyname` function (which is how Firefox resolves hostnames to IP addresses) and changes the hostnames FF tries to resolve - essentially doing a DNS hijacking for this specific process.

E.g., a lookup for `unwantedsite.example.com` gets converted into a lookup for `yourloggingserver.example.net` (and thus the HTTP request will go to `yourloggingserver.example.net`, although the request will still say `Host: unwantedsite.example.com`).

Normal operation:

- Firefox: gethostbyname("unwantedsite.example.com")
- DNS server: that host is at 10.20.30.40
- Firefox: connect to 10.20.30.40
- Firefox: `GET http://unwantedsite.example.com/`

"Hijacked" operation:

- Firefox: gethostbyname("unwantedsite.example.com")
- hooked DLL: modify to gethostbyname("yourloggingserver.example.net")
- DNS server: that host is at 192.168.1.54
- Firefox: connect to 192.168.1.54
- Firefox: `GET http://unwantedsite.example.com/`

Comment: Interesting, but that also uses a .exe and in the our current state the plugin is cross platform with a lot of MAC installs.. Ideas?

Comment: @Ryan: Fair point. How about this? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/blocksite/ Not sure if they're blocking at the DNS level though...

Comment: This may be interesting also: a DNS server that allows keyword-based redirection. Note that this will affect *every* client, not just Firefox, and you'd need to set this as the default DNS server for your network, and possibly block DNS requests to other servers (otherwise people can just pop in `8.8.8.8` as their DNS server and disregard your DNS server)